# Window.Open » getElementBy.open

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, web-applications

Is it possible to open the document,not in a new window, like 
this - `JavaScript.Window.Open(...)`

But in the same page, in `div` which we will take with    `getElementById`

I mean: `document.getElementById('name_of_div').Open(...)`

Also curious to know can I do it with an `iframe` or `XHR?`

please if the answer is very big. And you really don't have much time. Then answer it shortly :)  I want to learn it. Plz

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You just load the URL into the src property for the iframe element:

```js
var embedPg = document.getElementById("embedPage");
embedPg.src = "https://tinypng.com/";
```

```html
<iframe id="embedPage" src="">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```